# Do I need to install a LAMP server to run nodejs?

Tags: nodejs

Using Ubuntu 14.04 - I am trying to control an AR Drone Parrott using nodejs. My question is: Can I run nodejs without installing the LAMP packages?

On a netbook running UBUNTU 14.04 I have installed the ARDrone SDK by doing exactly this:
https://projects.ardrone.org/boards/1/topics/show/5942#message-6933. This worked perfectly.

I am trying to run the dancing drones tutorial/Flying Robots seen here:
http://2014.makerland.org/event/tutorials/drones/

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run NodeJS without the LAMP stack.  To run a node program you just need to have NodeJS installed along with the necessary libraries, then navigate in your terminal to the Directory where the code is located and run `node <filename>.js`.

Note: you can do this on Unix/ GNU+Linux/ and Windows.